# Create file with same name as directory without typing the filename possibly with brace expansion or some other trick

Tags: reactjs, bash

Let's say I have a directory called `Navigation` and inside that I want to make a file called `Navigation.jsx`.
Instead of doing `touch Navigation/Navigation.jsx` I'm trying to figure out if there is a trick to not have to type `Navigation` twice, such as brace expansion.
I tried stuff like `touch Navigation/{,.jsx}` and `touch Navigation/{/,.jsx}` but rather than removing the slash it only produces a file called `.jsx`.
When doing this many times for multiple components it gets really monotonous and I'd love a streamlined way of doing it. Hey, maybe I'm thinking about this all wrong and there's a different flow I should use to create folders and files.

Comment: You could name the file just `index.jsx` instead

Comment: Create a function in your `.bashrc` to do this job.

Comment: `touch "${PWD##*/}/${PWD##*}.jsx"`, might surprise you if the cwd is a symlink though.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions I've decided to write a script. It'll be better than my original idea since it'll take any number of arguments to create multiple components at once. I figured this has got to exist already but I'm more in the mood to code rather than research at the moment and it's simple to do.

Comment: You are worrying about the wrong things. Micro-optimizations are rarely worth the time or effort. That said, you could just create a function you provide a single argument to and have it output `touch $1/$1.jsx` and solve the problem that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did. Questions and comments welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    for arg in "$@"; do

        rfc="const $arg = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            $arg 
        </div>
    )
}

export default $arg 
"

        mkdir "$arg"/
        touch "$arg"/"$arg".jsx
        echo "$rfc" >>"$arg"/"$arg".jsx
        echo "Component $arg created at $arg/$arg.jsx"
    done

else
    echo "Enter component names as arguments"

fi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you put the directory names in a file, you could use a read while loop.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

find . -type d | sed '1d' | sed s'@^..@@g' > stack
while read n
do
mkdir "${n}"
touch "${n}"/"${n}"
done < stack
```